# Accessing Jenkins pipeline WorkflowScript during execution

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, workflowscript

I would like to know if there is a way to access the Jenkins Workflow script object during its execution.

I have a shared library, and I can pass this object to any groovy class as an argument, either directly from the Jenkins file, using 'this' keyword, or from any DSL in the vars folder, also using the 'this' keyword.

But I would like to access it using a method, even if this imply using reflexivity.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here example with pipeline, where `this` is a `script` object. Some other examples [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217736618-How-do-I-access-Pipeline-DSLs-from-inside-a-Groovy-class-):

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass()

pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        VAR1 = "var1"
        VAR2 = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo var2").trim()
        VAR3 = "var3"
    }

    stages {
        stage("Stage 1") {
            steps {
                script {
                    myClass.myPrint(this, "${VAR1}", "${VAR2}", "${VAR3}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyClass implements Serializable {
    void myPrint(def script, String var1, String var2, String... vars) {
        script.echo "myPrint: ${var1}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes this is a script object. However I want to access it from a shared library groovy class, without having to pass it as an argument to the constructor, or registering it to the library. I need a method, accessible from Jenkins, that will return me this object.

Comment: AFAIK, you have to pass it. But rather than accessing classes directly from your Jenkinsfile, wrap that in a var (e.g. in the example above `vars/myprint.groovy`, which can then pass the `this` object as a parameter (e.g. `script { myprint("${VAR1}", "${VAR2}", "${VAR3}") }` )